# Asp.net web application tool - application settings. SQL credentials?

Tags: asp.net, application-settings

Just wandering if its a good idea to put username and password in the application settings?

If not where is the best place to store these?

--Jonesy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since web.config is a protected file there will be no direct access to it. You will probably be fine storing your connection credentials there.

However - You can go a bit further and encrypt the appSettings in your web.config

[Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)

Comment: thanks web.conf is good enough. I actually though you had access to web.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files will be an ideal place for keeping the details about the database credential.But if you are worried about its security as its stored in plain text , then in asp.net you can encrypt a particular section of your webconfig file.Encyption can be done either by making use of aspnet_regiis.exe utility by providing relevant command line arguments.Otherwise encryption can also be done through code with the help of "**WebConfigurationManager**" class.Also You don’t need to unprotect a section in order to read the configuration settings in that section, the runtime will perform the decryption necessary for your application to read the plain text values.

E.g :- aspnet_regiis.exe

```
C:\>aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Projects\My Site"
```

here pdf argument is used to specify file path.

E.g :- Using WebConfigurationManager

```
protected void toggleEncryption(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration config;
    config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConnectionStringsSection section;
    section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
        as ConnectionStringsSection;
    if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
    }
    else
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
            "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
    }
    config.Save();
    WriteMessage("connections protected = " +
    section.SectionInformation.IsProtected);
}
```